# I am not understanding why my code is not working?

Tags: c++

I think this type of question is already been asked Sorry for that but can anyone tell me why this is wrong.

```
    int a[]={10,20,30,45,50};
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<=4;j++)
    {
            cout<<(*a);
            a++;
     }
```

okay so if pointer a in the above code cant be incremented then my the below code works,Is it just because pointer is first assigned to a variable and then its incremented.

```
  int  var[] = {10, 100, 200};
  int  i, *ptr;
  //let us have array address in pointer 
  ptr = var;
  for ( i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
  {
  printf("Value of var[%d] = %d\n", i, *ptr );
  // move to the next location 
  ptr++;
  }
```

Comment: what problem you found...?

Comment: The error is "lvalue required as increment operand"?

Comment: what do you want to perform..?

Comment: Print all the elements through a pointer a in my code.

Comment: please refer the below (lakesh's) answer....

Comment: Trust me, your next step will be "I have no idea why my code is working" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

*a refers to the first element of a[] which is 10. You will get an compiler error at a++. This is because you cannot increment value of a. *a is a constant pointer pointing to the first element of a[] and its address cannot be changed..

It should be:

```
 int a[]={10,20,30,45,50};
 int j;
 for(j=0;j<=4;j++)
 {
     cout<<*(a+j);
 }
```

Comment: but why an error am just incrementing a and dereferencing it then?

Answer (score 1):

**It doesn't compile because arrays are not pointers:**

---

With `int arr[] = {...}`:

- The values of `arr` and `&arr` are necessarily identical
- `arr` points to a valid memory address, but cannot be set to point to another memory address

---

With `int* ptr = ...`:

- The values of `ptr` and `&ptr` are not necessarily identical (in fact, they are mostly different)
- `ptr` can be set to point to both valid and invalid memory addresses, as many times as you will